# Writing mathematical notes in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have asked this question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/ but then i got a reply that it is off topic there and webmasters stack exchange site would be useful.

This is a continuation from my previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164670/convert-tex-file-to-html-in-miktex?noredirect=1#comment378543_164670

As I have realized that LaTeX cannot be put directly in WordPress pages, I tried to convert into HTML and use that in WordPress, and I am facing the following problem.

I would like to write some mathematical notes on a WordPress site.

I am expecting the output to be something like http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/stabilizer-commutes-with-conjugation-2/

But instead I am getting for the same content output as

[image]

I do not really understand what is the problem.

I think all the mathematical symbols in the Crazy Project link are actually images, whereas mine are just LaTeX code converted into HTML.

I am waiting for some better idea to convert my ugly looking statement to change to something like that in Crazy Project notes.

Another problem I am facing is:

I read that to write something in WordPress with LaTeX, I should just write `$latex {code }$`, but then it is showing the error "formula does not parse" in red colour.

What am I supposed to do with this kind of problem?

Am I not allowed to just copy the content of LaTeX code I have written before and paste it in WordPress?

If I am writing all those just by typing, I am not getting any problem, but if I copy the code then I get the "formula does not parse" error.

Answer (score 1):

> As I have realized that LaTeX cannot be put directly in WordPress pages

Are you sure you're doing it [right?](http://jetpack.me/support/beautiful-math-with-latex/)

The JetPack plugin comes with a LaTeX support module.  Simply install, enable, and TeX away.

Comment: I am not able to add plugin to my wordpress account... I could see that I have to download wordpress.org to activate my plugin.. It is all getting messed up... I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: JetPack exists by default on WordPress.com, it's included.  Something is wrong with your LaTeX formula, that's why things are breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I could now realize what my problem is :

I was actually thinking  writing

> $latex {what ever thing i write}$

would work nicely...

Now i realized my mistake..

I had my latex content say

> If $x^2=1$ then $x=\pm 1$

What I have done in wordpress is

> $latex  If $x^2=1$ then $x=\pm 1$ $

That is why this is giving a problem

what is should have done is instead

> If  $latex x^2=1$ then $latex  x=\pm 1$

This is giving me what i needed...

The problem is solved now...

Comment: Right..as I said you have an error in your formula.